# How to assign to function calls within a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to optimize some code to process lists of lists, and I notice that when I try to specify a list within a list that I keep running into errors with syntax or with my output.

My code is below

```
out = []
for cluster in ClusterFile:
    cluster = list(cluster)
    for term in cluster[3]:
        for item in Interest:
            if term == item[0]:
                x = [item[1]]
                cluster.append(x)
                break
        out.append(cluster)
        break
```

One of my many attempts:

```
out = [([item[1]]) for item in Interest for term in cluster[3] if term ==item[0] for cluster in ClusterFile]
```

Example input:

```
cluster = [['a'], [1, 2], [3, 4], [['w'], ['x'], ['y'], ['z']], [5, 6]]

Interest = [['w', 'qx12'], ['y', 'qx19']]
```

Example output:

```
[['a'], [1, 2], [3, 4], [['w'], ['x'], ['y'], ['z']], [5, 6], ['qx12', 'qx19']]
```

Does anyone know any resources that can help me solve this? I am coding in Python 3

Comment: Please provide example data, expected output, and the exact errors you're getting.

Comment: Well, for one, your `if` clause in your list comprehension is in the wrong place. It should be at the end, after `for cluster in ClusterFile`. On a separate note, is there a specific reason you want to use list comps? It seems introducing them just creates unnecessary complexity and reduces readability.

Comment: Thanks for your responses :) Yeah, I agree with your readability comment. I've used list comps to speed up other areas of this pipeline. This little segment is really slowing down my code though. All help and comments greatly appreciated

Comment: where is `id` defined?

Comment: id was changed to item, my bad!

Comment: Are you sure it's `cluster[3]` instead of `cluster[2]` because cluster of 3 is [5,6] and cluster of 2 is w,x,y,z

Comment: Sorry, typo on my behalf. I'm a final year PhD and have been working on this pipeline for the past 16 hours :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree with @blacksite that list comprehensions are not the most readable way to go here, if that's your goal, here's how to do it:

```
cluster.append(
    [x[0] for x in [[item[1] for item in Interest if term[0] == item[0]] 
                    for cluster in ClusterFile for term in cluster[2]] 
     if len(x)]
)

cluster
# [['a'], [1, 2], [['w'], ['x'], ['y'], ['z']], [5, 6], ['qx12', 'qx19']]
```

Data:

```
cluster = [['a'], [1, 2], [['w'], ['x'], ['y'], ['z']], [5, 6]]
ClusterFile = [cluster]
Interest = [['w', 'qx12'], ['y', 'qx19']]
```

A few notes:

- Nested list comprehensions work in the same order as nested for loops.  So if you have:

  ```
  for a in b:
      for x in a:
          f(x)
  ```

  then this looks like:

  ```
  [f(x) for a in b for x in a]
  ```

  That can seem a little backwards, as the `x in a` is far away from the front of the statement where `x` gets used.  Just think of it like the order of nested for loops.  (You had it backwards in the original code.)
- You want `cluster[2]`, not `cluster[3]`.
- When selecting individual elements in `cluster[2]`, e.g. `['w']`, `['x']`, etc., you were comparing the *list* element (`['w']`), represented by `term` against the *string* contained in that list (`'w'`), represented by `item[0]`.  That won't match, you need `term[0]` instead.
- The final list that gets appended (the list of `x[0]`s) drops a few empty lists that get created in the inner list comprehension.  That's not very pretty, there may be a better way to do that.  But again, this whole approach would be more readable without list comprehensions, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this to me :)

Comment: You're welcome!  If this answer resolves your question, please mark it accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks again, @andrew_reece!

Comment: You're welcome @Gloom.  I added one more note to my answer, about the order of nested list comprehensions.  Hope that helps.  Good luck on your PhD!